# GPX to Google Earth API

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, gpx

I have a website that users can download GPX files from and the manually upload them into Google Earth to view their journey. Is there a way to connect the website to Google Earth to automatically show them their journey rather than them having to download and reupload?

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth natively understands KML format but can also convert other formats (E.g. GPX, Shapefiles, CSV, etc.) into KML to view locally.

If the website URLs provided KML then you could create a KML file with a [Networklink](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink) which would automatically load the latest content when Google Earth was started and display the KML features.

But being the source are GPX files, Google Earth first needs to import and convert those files into KML to display. GPX is just XML and relatively easy to convert into KML so you may consider programatic scripting or coding options to fetch the GPX files then convert them into KML.